# Search Text File & Save Text as Variable (Outlook VBA)

Tags: vba, date

I am attempting to search an RTF file for the phrase "Creation Date: ", then save the year and month listed as variables to use in a later sub.

Because the dates will always be arranged in yyyy-mm-dd format within the file, I was hoping this could be accomplished by counting characters, so for:
Creation Date: 1994-08-17
The program would locate the words "Creation Date: ", save the next 4 characters as the year, skip the next character (the dash) and save the next two characters as the month, and so on.
I was thinking the sub would look something along the lines of:

```
Sub find()
    Const strFileName = "C:\Users\Username\Documents\whoisinfo.rtf"
    Const strSearch = "Creation Date: "
    'save next 4 characters as creyear (yyyy-mm-dd)
    Const strSearch = "Creation Date: "
    'skip 5 chars, save next 2 as cremonth
    Const strSearch = "Creation Date: "
    'skip 8 characters, save next 2 as creday
End Sub
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Which part *specifically* do you need help with?  Questions which begin "I need a macro that will..." and which include no code (even non-working code) tend to get fewer responses here than those that outline a particular problem that the questioner ran into while trying to solve the outlined problem.

Comment: I've been able to figure out how to open the file and find the "Creation Date: " string, but now I need help with having VBA look at the next characters and save them as variables.

Comment: `Instr()` will give you the position of your search string, then you can use `Mid(yourString, start_pos, length)` to pull out the three sub-strings you want.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have created the RTF yourself and have control over the placement of the RTF tags, there is no reliable way of manually searching for the text within an RTF file.  The is due to the fact that the RTF specs allows you to sprinkle RTF codes within the RTF strings.  For example, all the 3 strings below are equivalent, and would display the same way:

Creation Date: 1994-08-17

Creation Date: {\plain} 1994-08-17

Creation Date: 1994-{\plain \f0\fs24 08-17}

The only reliable method is to use a rich-text-box control do to search/replace.